# Child Window's Closebox is Hidden Behind MenuStrip of Parent (C# .Net 5.0)

Tags: c#, parent-child, hidden, mdi

I appreciate if somebody help me to solve a problem related to maximize a child window inside parent. Here is code to create child;

```
                    Form2 frm = new Form2();
                    frm.TopLevel = false;
                    frm.MdiParent = this;
                    frm.TopMost = true;
                    frm.Show();
```

It actually shows as expected;

[image]

However, the problem occurs when I maximize child form. Closebox goes behind menustrip item of parent. Windows highlights them by a blue rectangle when I move mouse over their expected location;

[image]

They (minimize, maximize and close ) respond when I click blue rectangles :)

I manipulated MinimizeBox, MaximizeBox, Opacity, and Topmost properties of forms and got no result.

Any idea?

Comment: It's a bug: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/3029